# sqlplus doesn't log compilation errors in designated out file

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, ksh

Here is my shell script in which I invoke sqlplus:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

sqlplus $USER/$PASSWD@$DB<<!!>./logFile.log

SELECT 'IN sqlplus' FROM dual;

DECLARE tbl_xst integer;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO tbl_xst FROM SYS.ALL_TABLES
WHERE table_name = 'SOME_TABLE'
AND OWNER = 'SOME_OWNER';

IF tbl_xst = 1 THEN
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE SOME_OWNER.SOME_TABLE;
END
END IF

SELECT 'The end' FROM dual;
!!
```

When I run the shell script and look into the log file logFile.log, this is what's there:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Mon Oct 22 12:33:05 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2006, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> SQL>
'INSQLPLUS
----------
IN sqlplus

SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15  Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Releas
e 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options
```

As you can see, the first logging SELECT statement ('IN sqlplus') makes it in while the second on at the bottom doesn't, i.e. the execution doesn't reach it because there is an error in between. Why isn't sqlplus writing this error message in the log file?

**EDIT AFTER SOME COMMENTS:**  We have established it is most likeley due to sqlplus not dumping STDERR into the specified log file, in which only STDOUT goes.  How do I format the sqlplus command to combine both streams (STDOUT and ERR) to go in the specified log file?  I suspect the `<<!!>` is critical here.

**EDIT AFTER MORE EXPERIMENTATION:**  Weirdly enough, SOME error messages are getting dumped in STDOUT, i guess properly syntaxed ones which attempt to reference bad DB objects.  If there is a SQL compilation error, it apparently goes in STDERR.  What I did is inser the following line after the first SELECT above and DECLARE:

```
DROP TABLE FAKE_NONEXISTING;
```

The statement is legit and it compiles, yet FAKE_NONEXISTING doesn't exist and I get the following in the log file:

```
SQL> SQL> DROP TABLE FAKE_NONEXISTING
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

However, I don't get anything in the log file for what appear to be SQL compilation errors

Comment: how do i change the line that invokes sqlplus to direct STDERR into a defined file?  better yet, how do i combine both STDOUT and ERR to go in the same log file?

Comment: actually, it needs to be formatted differently for sqlplus intake

Comment: i actually question the hypothesis that "its not being printed on stdout its being printed on stderr" because when you are inside sqlplus manually (so not invoking from a script), you get both errors and regular output in the same stream

Comment: i am thinking it has something to do with the <<!!> syntax in the sqlplus line

Answer (score 1):

SQL*Plus doesn't separate output to `stdout` and `stderr`. It's nothing to do with redirection or the shell really; you'd have the same issue if you pasted that code into an interactive SQL*Plus session. You aren't seeing a compilation error because you haven't told it you've supplied the complete block that needs to be compiled and executed.

Once you start [a PL/SQL block](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/overview.htm#i8859) - in this case with `DECLARE` - everything that comes after that is treated as part of the same block until you supply a [terminating `.`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663), or `/`, which [tells SQL*Plus to execute the current buffer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#sthref293), which here is the entire anonymous block. The second plain `select` that you expect to print `The end` is treated as part of the incomplete block, so that's never run either. Your script terminates (at `!!`) before it encounters a `/`, since you don't have one, so SQL*Plus doesn't ever know to execute anything. If you did paste it into SQL*Plus you'd see the same output and the cursor waiting for input on line 15; the scripted version is killed at that point, very roughly equivalent to hitting ctrl-C while a shell script is waiting for input.

But you're also missing a couple of other key parts of the block. If you add `BEGIN` and `END` around the procedural section and the terminating `/` you'll start to see the errors, some of which are just from missing semi-colons; this should get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

sqlplus $USER/$PASSWD@$DB<<!!>./logFile.log

SELECT 'IN sqlplus' FROM dual;

DECLARE -- start of PL/SQL block declaration
    tbl_xst integer;
BEGIN -- start of the actual block
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO tbl_xst FROM SYS.ALL_TABLES
    WHERE table_name = 'SOME_TABLE'
    AND OWNER = 'SOME_OWNER';

    IF tbl_xst = 1 THEN
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE SOME_OWNER.SOME_TABLE; -- this will error
    END; -- missing semi-colon, but separate BEGIN/END wrapper isn't really needed
    END IF; -- missing semi-colon
END; -- missing end to the block
/ - missing PL/SQL terminator/executor

-- now back in plain SQL mode
SELECT 'The end' FROM dual;
!!
```

That should now report an error around `DROP`. That is a DDL command and can't be run like that within PL/SQL; you have to use dynamic SQL, something like:

```
    IF tbl_xst = 1 THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE SOME_OWNER.SOME_TABLE';
    END IF;
```

(which is what William Stearns mentioned, though I'd strongly suggest you do *not* have an exception block with `WHEN OTHERS` and no `RAISE` since it'll swallow any error that occurs when it tries to drop the table.)

Incidentally, if you don't want to see the SQL*Plus version, connect and prompt/line number information in the output, you can use the [-s[ilent]](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#sthref226) option to suppress it.

Answer (score -2):

To redirect the error output as well to your logfile, you'd want to append 2>&1 to your line here:

```
sqlplus $USER/$PASSWD@$DB<<!!>./logFile.log 2>&1
```

Updated from my own comment... and I would probably add the >> instead of the > to append existing file so your log could be used over time.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

sqlplus $USER/$PASSWD@$DB<<+EOF>>./logFile.log 2>&1

SELECT 'IN sqlplus' FROM dual;

BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE SOME_OWNER.SOME_TABLE';
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;

SELECT 'The end' FROM dual;
+EOF
```

Comment: I guess the <<!! takes input from the rest of the script.  Could also use a marker like <<+EOF and place +EOF at the end of the file.

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't do.  the output is the same:  first print works, second never reached, no useful error message for the failure in between.

Comment: check the latest post amendment above starting with EDIT AFTER MORE EXPERIMENTATION:

Comment: Yeah, you're not handling the exception.  Let me just shorten it up for deleting a specific table if it exists.

Comment: i understand the DROP TABLE IF EXISTS syntax, however, what's unclear is how to get all out (standard and error) in the log file.  thanks

Comment: I'd have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058020/redirect-plsql-error-message-to-a-log-file-when-executing-it-in-sqlplus